# Capture redirect url in wkwebview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

How do I capture the redirection url in when using WKWebView like if a webpage redirects to another page on submitting the username and password or some other data. I need to capture the redirected url. Is there any method in WKNavigationDelegate to override?

Comment: hi yesterday your problem is resolved or not

Comment: Got resolved by using wkwebview

Comment: good but you are not informed me

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use this `WKNavigationDelegate` method

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void) {
        if(navigationAction.navigationType == .other) {
            if let redirectedUrl = navigationAction.request.url {
                //do what you need with url
                //self.delegate?.openURL(url: redirectedUrl)
            }
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it's not working anymore now navigationAction.navigationType => .other for redirect

Comment: @sheshnath thanks I will review and update my answer

Comment: @ShauketSheikh 16/08/2018

Comment: ok @ShauketSheikh I will review it again, anyway check for the another answer maybe can help you, let me know

Comment: Thanks but i am facing very wierd issue for wkwebview ios 9  cookie are not updating for redirect uri

Comment: WKWebView doesn't automatically set the Content-Type header to application/x-www-formurlencoded for POST requests 

You can add   request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type"). to headers manually

Comment: this method calling multiple time for same url

Answer (score 47):

(This answers the slightly more general question of how to detect a URL redirection in WKWebView, which is the search that lead me to this page.)

**Short answer**

Use `WKNavigationDelegate`'s `webView(_:didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation:)` function and examine `WKWebView`'s `URL` property.

**Longer answer**

There are a couple of places you could detect a server-side redirect.

On iOS 10.3.3 and iOS 11.0, the sequence of events I observe when loading a URL that gets redirected by the server is:

1. The `WKNavigationDelegate` function
   `webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)` is called for the
   original URL request. `WKWebView`'s `URL` property is set to the
   original URL.
2. The `WKNavigationDelegate` function `webView(_:didStartProvisionalNavigation:)` is called for the
   original URL request. `WKWebView`'s `URL` property is set to the
   original URL.
3. The `WKWebView`'s `URL` property is updated by WebKit to the redirection URL. (You'll only know about this if you are key-value
   observing the property.)
4. The `WKNavigationDelegate` function `webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)` is called for the
   redirected URL request. `WKWebView`'s `URL` property is then
   redirection URL.
5. The `WKNavigationDelegate` function `webView(_:didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation:)` is
   called. `WKWebView`'s `URL` property is the
   redirection URL.

(Note: On the iOS 11.0 simulator I have seen steps 3 and 4 reversed, with the `URL` property unchanged in `webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)`, which actually seems like a sensible ordering, but I haven't observed this on a device.)

It seems like the `webView(_:didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation:)` is built explicitly for the purpose of detecting redirects so is probably the preferred option, although the redirect could be possibly be inferred at steps 3 or 4 but only if you can be sure that there are no other causes of navigational change.

Comment: Underrated answer. The `didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation` should be the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 10):

After trying all the solutions, finally this one works for me using Swift 5 and WKWebView.This solution implements KVO for Swift

```
var webView: WKWebView?
var webViewObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    webViewObserver = webView?.observe(\.url, options: .new, changeHandler: {
        (currentWebView, _) in
        //      Here you go the new path
        currentWebView.url
    })
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    webViewObserver?.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me with my Vue 2 website where the page is not fully reloaded when pushing new paths to the Router

Comment: Thank you so much :) you saved my day :)

Answer (score 7):

Swift 5  Boom

Very easy way

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    if let url = webView.url?.absoluteString{
        print("url = \(url)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For me, using **`decidePolicyFor` navigation delegate's method didn't work**.

It didn't work because WKNavigationDelegate's method

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

will only be called when there is a full-page reload. 
To be able to catch all WKWebView's request URL changes, a Key-Value observer will have to be placed on the WKWebView's URL property.

**First**, in viewDidLoad add:

```
webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)
```

**Second**, add observeValue method

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == #keyPath(WKWebView.url) {
            // Whenever URL changes, it can be accessed via WKWebView instance
            let url = webView.url
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting, but can I get a document about this?

Comment: This answer actually helped me a lot! My delegate method are not called either because the web view is not doing a full page reload, but its url did change.


Also refer to @fmnavarretem answer's KVO syntax, it is in my opinion easier to understand. Also don't forget removing the observer on `deinit` or `viewWillDisappear`

Answer (score 2):

Credits to **Sven:** https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117073

If you are facing a situation that your WebView doesn't open a PDF file or simply the url resolves to nothing, because the WebView's redirect URL doesn't come through you can use `WKUIDelegate` function `webView(_:createWebViewWith:for:windowFeatures:)` to capture the failed call and load the request again like:

```
extension WebViewWrapper: WKUIDelegate {

 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
     if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil || navigationAction.targetFrame?.isMainFrame == false {
         webView.load(navigationAction.request)
     }
     return nil
 }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Use this WKNavigationDelegate method. I got redirect url from sourceFrame.request

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void) {
        let urlString = navigationAction.sourceFrame.request.url?.absoluteString ?? ""
        print("\(urlString)")
        decisionHandler(.allow)
 }
```