# Change HTTPHeaderField of redirected URL in WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I load a specific URL with additional HTTP headers - `setValue("OAuth " + token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`. Afterward, WKWebView implicitly redirects to another URL (it's okay), but without these headers. Is there a way of changing the `HTTPHeaderField` of URL before opening?

I've looked at `didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation`, but out of luck.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/45604336/5329717 ? Have you tried any of those approaches to begin with?