# How to intercept "a redirect URL" from webview in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm displaying an OAtuh2 HTML page in WebView that returns me, after clicking on a validation button that is on this page, a redirect URL that I would like to intercept to use the information from it.

**in XML file**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <WebView x:Name="browser"></WebView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**in CS file**

```
browser.Source = "https://myUrl";
```

My low knowledge in Xamarin doesn't allow me to know how to do it

Thanks for your help

Comment: See [WebView - Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos#events), and its `WebNavigatingEventArgs`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve on the WebNavigatingEventArgs witch "property" corresponding to the "redirect URL" ? Because e.Url return me the current URL and not the redirect one.

Comment: If you look at e.Source in debugger, it should contain either an `HTMLWebViewSource` or a `URLWebViewSource`. Which is it? And does it contain the original URL? If not, then in code behind for your WebView, what does `this.Source` contain? Should still be the original URL there, AFAIK.

Comment: It's URLWebViewSource that is triggered that contains only the original URL. And It triggers when the page is loaded, and not after the user clicked the "button validation", so when I will received the "redirect URL". So I tried WebNavigatedEventArgs to see if I can have later, but It's never trigger.

Comment: ok, I misunderstood. Sorry, I don't know why it does not trigger again when you click that button. The button takes you to another page, right?

Comment: I found out! I did both solutions, the one from ColeX and the one from you, to see how it works. When your doing this, your solution doesn't work. I've deleted ColeX solution and it works. Anyway Thank you so much for your patience with me, you're helped me a lot to progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as  ToolmakerSteve mentioned  using `WebNavigatingEventArgs`.

And for details you can implement this on each specific platform with custom renderer .

##### iOS

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp.iOS
{
    class MyRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            this.NavigationDelegate = new MyDelegate();
        }
    }

    public class MyDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {
        public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy> decisionHandler)
        {
            if(navigationAction.NavigationType == WKNavigationType.Other)
            {
                if(navigationAction.Request.Url != null)
                {
                    //do something
                }
                decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Cancel);
                return;
            }
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow);
        }
    }
}
```

##### Android

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp.Droid
{
    class MyRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyRenderer(Context context):base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetWebViewClient(new MyClient());
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
        {
            //do something
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45604360/8187800

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4066497/8187800

Comment: What proposed @ToolmakerSteve and your proposal are 2 different ways to get "redirect URL" ?

Comment: the problem now is how to get value from the xamarin.andorid or ios to xamarin.form ?

Comment: @JBD *"'how to get value from the xamarin.andorid or ios to xamarin.form"* - https://stackoverflow.com/q/24251020/199364, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center