# Catching Content Change in WebView for a Blazor WASM Page in MAUI

Tags: webview, navigation, maui, blazor-webassembly

There is a blazor webassembly website and I need to store the latest url that user displays in a webview in a MAUI app.

I created a WebViewRenderer and gave a new custom webviewclient via SetWebViewClient method. But unfortunately no method in the WebViewclient is triggered/hit.

The app hits the ConnectHandler so it means that I can successfully connect to handler. I give you anyway my code but not sure if it really helps.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MiniApp.Platforms.Android
{
 public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewHandler
 {
    CustomWebViewClient webclient;
    public MyWebViewRenderer()
    {
        webclient = new CustomWebViewClient();

    }

    protected override void ConnectHandler(global::Android.Webkit.WebView platformView)
    {
        //platformView.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

        base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
    }

    protected override global::Android.Webkit.WebView CreatePlatformView()
    {
        var platformView = base.CreatePlatformView();
        platformView.SetWebViewClient(webclient);
        return platformView;
    }

}
public class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public override void OnPageStarted(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, string? url, Bitmap? favicon)
    {
        base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    public override void DoUpdateVisitedHistory(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, string? url, bool isReload)
    {
        base.DoUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);
    }

    public override void OnFormResubmission(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, Message? dontResend, Message? resend)
    {
        base.OnFormResubmission(view, dontResend, resend);
    }

    public override void OnLoadResource(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, string? url)
    {
        base.OnLoadResource(view, url);
    }

    public override void OnPageCommitVisible(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, string? url)
    {
        base.OnPageCommitVisible(view, url);
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, string? url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    public override void OnReceivedClientCertRequest(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, ClientCertRequest? request)
    {
        base.OnReceivedClientCertRequest(view, request);
    }

    public override bool OnRenderProcessGone(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, RenderProcessGoneDetail? detail)
    {
        return base.OnRenderProcessGone(view, detail);
    }

    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, IWebResourceRequest? request)
    {
        return base.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }

    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, string? url)
    {
        return base.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }

    public override void OnUnhandledInputEvent(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, InputEvent? e)
    {
        base.OnUnhandledInputEvent(view, e);
    }

    public override void OnScaleChanged(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, float oldScale, float newScale)
    {
        base.OnScaleChanged(view, oldScale, newScale);
    }

    public override void OnSafeBrowsingHit(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, IWebResourceRequest? request, [GeneratedEnum] SafeBrowsingThreat threatType, SafeBrowsingResponse? callback)
    {
        base.OnSafeBrowsingHit(view, request, threatType, callback);
    }
}
}
```

Is there a way to catch the url when user navigates?

PS: I use vs 2022 and .net 8.0 framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new project and reproduce your problem. It appears to be a new issue  in the .net 8.0. You can report it [on the github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

In addition, you can try to use the custom handler in the page's OnHandlerChanged method as a workaround.

In the xaml:

```
<Webview x:Name="webview" Source=""/>
```

And in the code behind:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
       base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if ANDROID
       (webview.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView).SetWebViewClient(new Platforms.Android.MyClient());
#endif
}
```

And the WebViewClent class:

```
namespace MauiApp.Platforms.Android
{
    public class MyClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, IWebResourceRequest? request)
        {
            var url = request.Url.ToString();
            // this is the url
            return base.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, the `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]` should be delete because it is used in xamarin.forms not maui.

**Update:**

For the windows, you can use the webview's navigated event to do that:

In the xaml:

```
<WebView Navigated="webview_Navigated" HeightRequest="800" x:Name="webview"
```

In the code behind:

```
        private void webview_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
#if WINDOWS
            var webview2 = webview.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2;
            var url = webview2.Source.ToString();
#endif
        }
```

**Update2:**

For the iOS, you can refer to this case: [Capture redirect url in wkwebview in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604336/capture-redirect-url-in-wkwebview-in-ios), or just debug to check which method of the `WKNavigationDelegate` will be called.

And for the Windows, you can check the official document: [Navigation events for WebView2 apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/navigation-events). And you can also debug to check which event will be called. Such as:

```
        protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
        {
            base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if ANDROID
            (webview.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView).SetWebViewClient(new Platforms.Android.MyClient());
#elif WINDOWS
            var webview2 = webview.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2;
            var url = webview2.Source.ToString();
            webview2.CoreWebView2.HistoryChanged += (s,e) =>
            {
                var url = s.Source;
            };
            webview2.CoreWebView2.SourceChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                var url = s.Source;
            };
            // and the other event
#endif
        }
```

**Solution:**

For the android, use the custom handler above and over ride the DoUpdateVisitedHistory method.

For the windows, use the webview2's event above.

For the iOS, refer to [op's solution on the github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19232#issuecomment-1843279892).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For Android it works but ShouldOverrideUrlLoading does not hit but DoUpdateVisitedHistory method hits and I can get the url.

I've tried with Windows and unfortunately no success. I initialized some events but no response. I have not yet ios (because there is an issue with provisioning) but if you know which event it hits, it would be great. 

I'll report that bug too.

Comment: I tested a common website not a blazor-webassembly and the ShouldOverrideUrlLoading was hit. Did you try some other website? @ertan2002

Comment: For the ios, you can add a `WKNavigationDelegate` for the webview and override the `DecidePolicy` method. @ertan2002

Comment: Unfortunately I had some irrelevant issues but now it is ok. As you said if I use a regular website like google.com, then ShouldOverrideUrlLoading hits but if I use a blazor wasm webiste then only DoUpdateVisitedHistory and OnLoadResource. DoUpdateVisitedHistory  method gives me the correct url. OnLoadResource gives api call and favicon url. 

I'll test ios thank you. And do you have an idea also for windows? I could not find it

Comment: For the windows, please check the update part in my answer. @ertan2002

Comment: And I found it also worked for the iOS. @ertan2002

Comment: Thank you for your updated message Liyun, but unfortunately it does not work for windows, nor iOS. My issue is  the webassembly (maybe SPA) pages. I can already get urls from the regular websites. webview_Navigated does not hit when I navigate in our webassembly page. I also tried DecidePolicy method in iOS, in the beginning it hits, but when I navigate in the website, it does not navigate either. Till now I achive this aim in Android by using DoUpdateVisitedHistory. For windows and for ios there is no solution yet and for me actualyl ios is the most important one

Comment: Please check the update2 part in my answer. @ertan2002

Comment: thank you so much.  Now I can grab the url in windows but there is probem still in ios. I've tried to use AddObserver method but it crashes. Anway, I created an issue in dotnet github and https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19232 I created a repo that you can test also for ios if you would like to.

Comment: I've finally solved the issue.  I am going to update your answer and accept it as answer.  Thank you for your help. It helped me a lot to overcome this issue. Otherwise we would have to play with js in the website and invoke from the maui that I did not want :)

Comment: Glad to know you have resolved it. And I have updated my answer. @ertan2002